# Program seems to bypass a line of code

Tags: java, string, boolean

I need to have this code identify a character that is not a letter. Well, thats not all it does, but that's the problem I'm having.  I thought I had the right code, and it seems like it works, but it also picks up on letters. Heres the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class AlphaPos {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" Please enter an upper or lowercase letter. ");
           String letter = input.nextLine();
           String alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
           String beta = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

         if ((letter != alpha) && (letter != beta));
              System.out.println(" You entered " +letter+ ", and you obviously can't follow directions."); 

        boolean hasUppercase = !letter.equals(letter.toLowerCase()); {
           if (hasUppercase) 
              System.out.println("Your letter is " +letter+ ", Uppercase, and its number is "+ beta.indexOf(letter));

        boolean hasLowercase = !letter.equals(letter.toUpperCase());
           if (hasLowercase)
                 System.out.println("Your letter is " +letter+ " ,lowercase , and its number is "+ alpha.indexOf(letter));
                                                                      }   

   }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing single letter to whole upper or lowercase alphabet?

Comment: School project. It has no real purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your code shows significant confusion about how Java works.

```
String letter = input.nextLine();
```

This reads an entire line, not just a single letter

```
String alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String beta = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
if ((letter != alpha) && (letter != beta));
```

This last line does not examine `letter` to see if it matches one of the characters.  It compares `letter` and `alpha` to determine if they are references to the same string, which they never will be.

Also, the trailing semicolon terminates the statement, so the following line

```
System.out.println(" You entered " +letter+ ", and you obviously can't follow directions.");
```

executes regardless of anything before it -- it is not the "then" part of the `if` statement.

Let's assume for a minute that the user entered a single letter followed by the ENTER key.  If you wanted to verify that the character was a letter or s space you would do something like this:

```
if (letter.matches("[a-zA-Z ]") ...
```

but that would work only if a single character was entered.  I could go on but you need to learn quite a bit more about Java, and StackOverflow is not really a tutorial site.

Comment: I am an extreme beginner in Java, so thats why this code isn't great. Any tips on how to get it to work, though?

Answer (score 0):

To check if user typed a letter you should use `contains` method. It's not working because you are comparing single letter to whole strings (in this case comparing `letter` to `alpha` and then to `beta`) what isn't what you wanted to accomplish. Code sample:

`if((!alpha.contains(letter))&&(!beta.contains(letter))) {
    //do smith
}`

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing the input to your alpha or beta variable values, which will never match any unique and valid letter.

Recommended changes:

- The semicolon after your "if" is annulling the effect of the
  condition, the line "System.out.println..." would always run with
  that. Remove the semicolon (and even better, add braces after the
  condition)
- Remove the leading spaces in 'alpha' and 'beta'
- Ensure that the user supplied **only one letter by either validating or
  taking the first character**
- Then, assuming letter has only one character, you can change your condition to:

  ```
      if(!(alpha.contains(letter) || beta.contains(letter)))
  ```

So I'd make these changes:

```
        //Changed this line to use the first non-blank character
        //You may need to perform a length check before calling substring.
        String letter = input.nextLine().trim().substring(0, 1);
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String beta = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        if(!(alpha.contains(letter) || beta.contains(letter))){
            System.out.println(" You entered " +letter+ ", and you obviously can't follow directions.");
        }
        //And the rest of your code...
```